# REGEX to split comma delimited string capturing empty strings for all blank sections

Tags: regex

I found some javascript regex that captures all comma delimited fields even if they are empty:

```
(("[^"]*")|[^,]+)|(?=,(,|$))
```

However, it doesn't capture first field if its empty.  Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/h7vb4U/1

Anyone know how I can make it capture the first empty field?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```php
"([^"]*)"|([^,]+)|(?<=,|^)(?=,|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h7vb4U/3).

**Details**

- `"([^"]*)"` - a substring in between double quotation marks that cannot have other double quotation marks
- `([^,]+)` - 1+ non-comma chars
- `(?<=,|^)(?=,|$)` - a location between a comma or start of string and a comma or end of string.